Estimating Power by simulation - Sensitivity
I'm working on a project in which two different tests which given a binary outcome are being compared, and we want to evaluate the tests by their sensitivity.  Not surprisingly, the question of how many samples are needed to achieve a certain degree of power has come up.  Fortunately, it has come up a priori, so this is not a post-hoc power calculation.
I know there are a number of ways to compare the sensitivities of two test with binary outcomes - Fisher's Exact Test, McNemar's Test, and Test of Proportions.  Additionally, we have an estimate of the sensitivity for the first test, about 75%.  In order to calculation the Power at different sample sizes, I wrote the R function shown below.
I've tried to compare my results to some literature sources, but all of the sources I've found so far don't specify some of the details of the tests, such as which particular test is used, whether they assumed independence of the tests (were the two tests run on the same individuals or on two different groups of individuals?), level of significance, etc.
For my code, I've assumed the two tests are run on different groups, and I have specified all the other assumptions in the code.  Does this look correct?  If not, I would appreciate any advice.  How would I perform the simulation if the two tests were run on the same subjects?  I assume I'll need to account for the expected correlation between the two tests, but I'm unsure of how to do that.  Additionally, am I correct that this same simulation could be done to estimate power for specificity comparisons?
set.seed(303)

se1 <- .75  # sensitivity (or specificity) of test 1
se2 <- .80  # sensitivity (or specificity) of test 2

Nd <- 60  # number dz per group
Z <- 10000 # number of trials
alpha = 0.05 # target significance level

powercalc(se1, se2, Nd, Z, alpha, 'fisher')

#####
powercalc <- function(se1, se2, Nd, Z, alpha, 
    test = c('fisher', 'mcnemar', 'proportion')){
  p_vals <- sapply(1:Z, function(z) {
    s1_pos <- rbinom(1, Nd, se1)  
  # sample the possible test results with binomial
    s1_neg <- Nd - s1_pos
    s2_pos <- rbinom(1, Nd, se2)
    s2_neg <- Nd - s2_pos
    
# create a matrix with the rows corresponding to the two tests
# and the columns coresponding to the outcomes of those tests
# these are the results for the subjects with the condition for 
# sensitivity
# or the subjects without the condition for specificity
    m <- matrix(c(s1_pos, s1_neg,
                  s2_pos, s2_neg),
                nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
    
    if(test == 'fisher')
      fisher.test(m)$p.value
else if(test == 'mcnemar')
  mcnemar.test(m)$p.value
    else if(test == 'proportion')
      prop.test(c(s1_pos, s2_pos), c(Nd, Nd))$p.value
  })
  
  # count the number of times we see the extreme arrangement
  
  # for two-sided test
  lte_alpha = mean(p_vals <= alpha / 2)
  gte_alpha = mean(p_vals >= 1 - (alpha /2))
  power_2sided = lte_alpha + gte_alpha
  beta_2sided = 1 - power_2sided
  
  # for one sided, assuming test two has higher sensitivity
  beta_1sided = mean(p_vals >= alpha)
  power_1sided = 1 - beta_1sided
  
  c(one_sided = power_1sided, two_sided = power_2sided)
}

